Questions about batteries and circuits
If the electrical potential difference is the difference in potential energy over charge
Say we have a circuit, we plug it into a 1.5V battery, does that mean that for every coulomb of electrons moving from the negative terminal to the positive terminal, they would lose 1.5eV of electrical potential energy?

no each electron has 1.5eV. So 1 coulumb would have 1.5/1.6e-19  eV.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt

Voting to reopen. Obviously a conceptual question and not a homework question.


does that mean that for every coulomb of electrons moving from the negative terminal to the positive terminal, they would lose 1.5eV of electrical potential energy?

No, each individual electron moving through the circuit loses 1.5 eV of energy.
A whole coulomb moving through the circuit would lose about $9.36\times 10^{18}$ eV, which is equal to 1.5 J.

I meant to say 1.5J of Energy, not eV. Not idea where that typo came from
